# Why would a package be installed from a repo and not another?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, systemd

I use `systemd` (xenial) and want o be up to date. To do so, I [install Martin Pitt's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/ubuntu/systemd) and everything is fine.

On one system (not special in any way, this is a clean install actually), despite the PPA being configured ...

```
root@eu11:~# apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/systemd/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Fetched 102 kB in 0s (297 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

... `systemd` is installed from the standard repository.

```
root@eu11:~# apt show systemd
Package: systemd
Version: 229-4ubuntu17
Priority: required
Section: admin
Origin: Ubuntu
```

What can be the reason for such behaviour? (I did not configure any pinning because I do not know how to do it, never having had the need before)

This is the output of `apt-cache policy systemd` :

```
root@eu11:~# apt-cache policy systemd
systemd:
  Installed: 229-4ubuntu17
  Candidate: 229-4ubuntu17
  Version table:
 *** 229-4ubuntu17 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     229-4ubuntu10 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     229-4ubuntu4 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy systemd`?

Comment: @muru: I updated the question with the output, thanks.

Comment: You said you're on 16.04, but [the PPA only provides systemd for 17.04](https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/ubuntu/systemd?field.series_filter=xenial). I suppose the question now is, how did the PPA package get installed on the other systems? O.o

Comment: @muru: OK,now I understand. This system is on xenial, the others are on zesty. I was under the (wrong) impression that the packages were for all systems. I am now stuck :) Thank you for your help, if you could just turn your comment into an answer I would gladly accept it.

Comment: ali76's answer says pretty much the same thing, you can accept that.

Answer (score 5):

Because this PPA has `systemd` package only for the `zesty` (17.04) distribution.

As you can see in the following links, this PPA has the `indicator-session` package for `Xenial` (16.04) and the `systemd` package for `zesty` (17.04).

[indicator-session link for xenial](https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/ubuntu/systemd?field.series_filter=xenial)

[systemd link for zesty](https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/ubuntu/systemd?field.series_filter=zesty)